# Why is an (NVIDIA) GPU L1 cache line longer than an L2 cache line?

Tags: caching, gpgpu, cpu-cache, micro-architecture

In NVIDIA Fermi and Kepler GPUs (probably Maxwell too), an L1 cache line is 128-bytes long, while an L2 cache line is 32-byte long. Shouldn't that be the other way around? I mean, L1 is much smaller, shouldn't it try to cache shorter segments of memory to prevent thrashing?

Comment: Memory transactions are nominally warp wise, and warps contain 32 threads. A 128 byte L1 cache line corresponds to each thread in a warp reading a 32 bit word (the standard transaction size). Makes sense to me.....